# separate columns with condition

Tags: r, csv, data-manipulation, movies

I have a csv file from movielens that i'm trying to manipulate.

The movie list in my data.frame contains movie title and the year of movie and what i'm trying to separate the year and title to separate columns.

I used the folowing code:

```
movies <- extract(movies, title, c("title", "year"), "^(.*) \\(([0-9 \\-]*)\\)$")
```

I succeded to that but there is movies that contains only names and for those movies i get NA for the hole rows instead of getting NA for only "Year" column.

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]? Then people will be better able to help.

Comment: In particular, please include the output of `dput(movies[1:10,])` in your question.

Comment: try using `separate` function

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELfwb.png)

This is how the results looks